# Execute method infinitely in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, queue, infinite-loop

I have requirement of reading java queue elements (ConcurrentLinkedQueue) in springboot infinitely (no jms or any messaging queues). From UI request, i will add the element to a queue per request, if queue contains any element it should read and this procedure is for infinite ( As many requests keep on hitting, i will add element to queue and that has to be executed in springboot). Please suggest how to do this.

Example:

> Queue = []  (initially) 1st request => Queue = ["1"] (added) A method
>   running infinitely should check queue elements, when elements  are
>   present in queue print them. 2nd request => Queue = ["2"]  A method
>   running infinitely should check queue elements, when elements  are
>   present in queue print them.
>
> and so on..

Thanks.

Comment: You have to implement Producer-Consumer Pattern. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274223/implementing-producer-consumer-in-java

Comment: i got producer-consumer pattern. my concern is how to make this in springboot. can u please ping  any model implementations.. m completely new with spring concurrency

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Spring Boot Reactive web service which works on publish subscribe model for asynchronous communication. Please look at [Spring Boot Reactive](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/)

If you do not want to create a web-service, better not use Spring Boot and create a plain java application instead.